# Flutter Firebase Authentication Google Sign In is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication to sign in with google. It is actually working on my computer properly. However I am working with my friend and we are using github. So in his computer the code is not working, there is no compile error just the function that we used is not functioning. Should we do firebase set-up on his computer too ? And what if we publish this on google play store Is it gonna work well ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your question is not clearly understandable. Your friend wanna use which part of Flutter Firebase ? And you think if you publish your product cant we use ? Absolutely we can. I think your questions answer is about some permissions of firebase. Check this out and firebase website:

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: I mean there is a button in my application about google sign in. And I can sign in and see the next page. Also I can see my google account on users page on firebase website. And when I did all of firebase setup(import libraries, changing gradles etc..) And he pulled this only from github. Should we apply some settings on his computer or Did I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I've added my SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate but I haven't added his yet.